# Need Help Replacing Deprecated Collision Code in Flutter's Flame Game Development"

Tags: flutter, flame

I'm developing a game with Flutter's Flame, but my code is deprecated, and I don't know how to replace this part. Can you help me?

```
 void onCollision(Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints, Collidable other) {
   super.onCollision(intersectionPoints, other);
   if (other is Attack) {
     removeFromParent();
     removeHitbox(hitboxRectangle);
     onTouch.call(other.position)
   }
 }

Thank you very much
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Which part is not working? Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: Collidable, or onCollision are not longer supporter in the new version of flame for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `Collidable` to `PositionComponent` and what you most likely want to do here is override `onCollisionStart` and not `onCollision`:

```dart
 void onCollisionStart(Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints, PositionComponent other) {
   super.onCollisionStart(intersectionPoints, other);
   if (other is Attack) {
     removeFromParent();
     onTouch.call(other.position)
   }
 }
```

You also don't have to remove the hitbox, since you are already removing the whole parent.

Also remember to use the correct mixin, `with CollisionCallbacks` instead of `with HasHitboxes` or whatever it used to be called.

Comment: Thank you very much, do I still need to use with GestureHitboxes and with HasCollisionDetection ?

Comment: Yes, those two mixins are still needed. `HasCollisionDetection` on the game and `GestureHitboxes` on the components that you want to be able to drag/tap on only the hitbox areas. And same on this one, can you mark the answer as the correct one with the checkmark. :)